# nomenclature and \verb|text|

Tags: verbatim, nomenclature, arara

I tried different solutions but without result
I have configured arara on texstudio to be able to use the [nomenclature package](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Nomenclatures).

```
\usepackage[refpage,intoc,italian]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{.\quad #1}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Physics Constants}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Number Sets}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
    ]}
```

I was going to build a nomenclature of my personal commands contained in a **mydef.tex** file

from the file **mydef.tex** I can pick up the useful definitions to the nomenclature, that I am going to insert in a **nomen.tex** file such as:

```
\mbox{}

\nomenclature[O]{$\ui$}{Velocità $i$-esima }
\nomenclature[O]{$\uij$}{....... $i$-esima }
\nomenclature[O]{$\uijj$}{....... $i$-esima }
```

[image]

I would like to **include** in the nomenclature not only the meaning of the symbol, but also the text of the command I use to represent it on latex, that is, I would like it to be:

\mbox{}

```
\nomenclature[O]{$\ui$}{Velocità $i$-esima \verb|\ui|}
\nomenclature[O]{$\uij$}{....... $i$-esima \verb|\uij|}
\nomenclature[O]{$\uijj$}{....... $i$-esima  \verb|\uijj|}
```

it would be possible ? do you have any suggestions?

thanks

---------------------**UPDATE**-----------------------------

minimal example :

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: true }
% arara: nomencl: {style: 'nomencl.ist'}
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }    
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }   
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
%%---------------------nomenclatura-----------------------------------
\usepackage[refpage,intoc,italian]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{.\quad #1}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Physics Constants}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Number Sets}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
    ]}
% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
\newrobustcmd{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
%%-------------fine nomenc--------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\ui}{\ensuremath{u_{i}}} %% u i-esima scalare
\newcommand{\uij}{\ensuremath{u_{i,j}}} %% u j-esima scalare
\newcommand{\uijj}{\ensuremath{u_{i,jj}}} %% u j-esima scalare
%\input{mydef}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
            \hline
            Simbolo & Significato & Comando\\ \hline

            \ui & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\ui|  \\
            \uij & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\uij|  \\
            \uijj & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\uijj|  \\
            \hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    This is a minimal working example and I would like to write: \\

    $\ui$ \qquad Velocità $i$-esima \qquad \verb|\ui|
    \\
    \printnomenclature

    \mbox{}
    \nomenclature[O]{$\ui$}{Velocità $i$-esima \cs{\ui}}
    \nomenclature[O]{$\uij$}{Velocità $i$-esima }
    \nomenclature[O]{$\uijj$}{Velocità $i$-esima} 
    \printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't use `\verb` in the argument of another command. You have to use something like `\string\ui` but make sure both don't get expanded, so more like `\noexpand\string\noexpand\ui` (but I'm not sure what exactly and won't look into it without a proper MWE).

Comment: You'd be better off defining a command that typesets the control sequence name. For example, `\newrobustcmd{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}` and then replace `\verb|\ui|` with `\cs{ui}`. (Aside from not being able to use verbatim in an argument, `|` is also a makeindex special character.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I entered the command but the result is not the desired one. I added a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\cs` like this: `\cs{ui}` and not `\cs{\ui}`, I've also included a slightly different implementation of `\cs` that gives a correct looking backslash:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
%%---------------------nomenclatura-----------------------------------
\usepackage[refpage,intoc,italian]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{.\quad #1}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Physics Constants}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Number Sets}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
    ]}
% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
\makeatletter
% quick and dirty method to get the correct backslash
\edef\mybackslash{\expandafter\@gobble\string\\}
\makeatother
\newrobustcmd{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\mybackslash #1}}
%%-------------fine nomenc--------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\ui}{\ensuremath{u_{i}}} %% u i-esima scalare
\newcommand{\uij}{\ensuremath{u_{i,j}}} %% u j-esima scalare
\newcommand{\uijj}{\ensuremath{u_{i,jj}}} %% u j-esima scalare
%\input{mydef}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
            \hline
            Simbolo & Significato & Comando\\ \hline

            \ui & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\ui|  \\
            \uij & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\uij|  \\
            \uijj & Velocità $i$-esima & \verb|\uijj|  \\
            \hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    This is a minimal working example and I would like to write: \\

    $\ui$ \qquad Velocità $i$-esima \qquad \verb|\ui|
    \\
    \printnomenclature

    \mbox{}
    \nomenclature[O]{$\ui$}{Velocità $i$-esima \cs{ui}}
    \nomenclature[O]{$\uij$}{Velocità $i$-esima \cs{uij}}
    \nomenclature[O]{$\uijj$}{Velocità $i$-esima \cs{uijj}} 
    \printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that to make a list of commands is more appropriate to use the table. I find the final result seen from the point of view of the nomenclature redundant.
thanks for the precious help and very useful to understand how to handle certain commands